# Missing Metadata Files

Tags: nft, ipfs, meta-data

When uploading the metadata & images to IPFS, some files(json) and images (png) were deleted from the initial file upload due to poor art output.

Example: 100 NFTs
Deleted: 3, 17, 88
Uploaded: 97 files of metadata and 97 distinct images

Now when minting, the skipped files (3, 17, 88) are actually being minted, but not yielding any detail (as they were never loaded).

Is there any way to load those skipped files, to ensure the NFT purchaser can see their art?

Comment: Can you share the NFT contract? Are you using a known framework?

Answer (score 0):

This would totally depend on your smart contract, however if you used a generic NFT contract, the `setURI` function points to one IPFS folder (CID).

It may be possible to create a mapping for each tokenId to point to a different CID but that is a particular case.

Are you the owner of the contract and can you change the URI ? If so, you can upload the complete collection (with your missing NFT metadata) to IPFS again, with a new CID. You may then change the URI with the `setURI` function, and your NFTs will point to the correct collection for all tokenIds.